# ASUS Laptop touchpad not working

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, asus

I am using Asus X450LA and Ubuntu 14.04. I am facing a problem with the touchpad. It is not working and the pointer is not visible either. I am using a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

This question already has an answer:

[Touchpad not recognized on Asus N550JK - TP500L (FocalTech)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609892/touchpad-not-recognized-on-asus-n550jk-focaltech)

I finally came to this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1372609

It seems the FocalTech touchpad needs a specific driver, and that work is in progress to integrate it into the mainline kernel.

There is [a PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms) to get a dkms driver for this touchpad

After trying this, I can confirm the following procedure works :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms
```

Reboot, and the touchpad in now recognized. Two finger scrolling works, for example. Also, the zone where the buttons are won't make the cursor move.

Thanks for the community that retro-engineered this (Asus just replied "no linux support nor technical information" to a request!

Credit goes to [alci](https://askubuntu.com/users/2330/alci) and [heemayl](https://askubuntu.com/users/216503/heemayl)

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on an ASUS X302L and these instructions worked for me.