# Asus K501UX touchpad not working Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, asus

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.3 on my Asus K501UX and the touchpad is failing to work. It does not appear in the devices and several other things I have attempted have failed. External mice do work.

I have tried [reloading the driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working):

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

[reinstalling the driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486916/touchpad-not-working-with-xubuntu-14-04):

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

adding ["psmouse.proto=bare" to the kernel cmdline](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314198/comments/31) and [whatever this is.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506826/asus-laptop-touchpad-not-working) None have worked.

My problem appears to be with the kernel as the device does not appear in /proc/bus/input/devices:

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
N: Name="Sleep Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=4000 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:22/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Asus WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=asus-nb-wmi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=100013
B: KEY=80000 0 800000000000 0 0 a1606f00900000 8200027800501000 e000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04f2 Product=b54b Version=9556
N: Name="USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-6/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0461 Product=4d81 Version=0111
N: Name="USB Optical Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:0461:4D81.0001/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=143
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

and nothing is mentioned in the output to xinput either:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ USB Optical Mouse id=10 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus id=8 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam id=11 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys id=12 [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard id=13 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Kernal support for Asus K501UX touchpad is available on v4.2. Finally got it to work after frantically searching everywhere for the driver.

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily`

Source: [Focaltech touchpad. Couldn't find synaptics properties.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644411/couldnt-find-synaptics-properties-no-synaptics-driver-loaded)