# Touchpad not working in Ubuntu 16.04 in ASUS-X454L

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, asus

I have just bought Asus-X454L couple of days back. I am using 16.04 as OS on my machine. Its touchpad worked fine with windows 10 pre-installed by the seller. It was working fine with Ubuntu 16.04 for the first few hours. Now it is not responding.

Here is my `xinput` result:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried to follow these links:

1. http://https://askubuntu.com/questions/506826/asus-laptop-touchpad-not-working
2. [Elantech Touchpad not working on Ubuntu 16.04 and Arch Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux)
3. [Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working)

But none of them worked for me. How can I fix this problem?
I using the whole HDD without any partition, and so could not try having a new setup.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: You do not need to be familiar with it. Just run it and add the output to your question.

Comment: I've added the output to the question.

Comment: The touchpad is not detected, the mouse is probably a real mouse. Check the bios settings.

Comment: I am using a real mouse because the touchpad is not working.

Comment: What's the output of the command `synclient`?  [edit] your answer, add it there and then leave a comment here @fabby.

Comment: @Fabby , here's the output of `synclient`:

"Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"

Comment: I concur with @Pilot6: check the BIOS settings...

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thank you for your co-operation.

Comment: How did you fix this?